# JSF: ui:include param for "for"-attribute

Tags: jsf, parameters, el, composition

I have swapped out a composition to re-use it. The composition contains tags like this:

```
<t:radio for=":someForm:someComponent" index="#{index}" />
```

I include the composition like this:

```
<ui:include src="/theComposition.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="someParam" value="#{someBean}" />
</ui:include>
```

But how can I parameterize the "someForm" part of the composition? Because that will differ depending on where I include it. I could pass a string... but how should I concatenate it? Or is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just inline EL in the attribute value.

```
<t:radio for=":#{someParam}:someComponent" index="#{index}" />
```

Comment: Perfect - I didn't know it was that easy.